# android linked list of listeners

Tags: android, list, listener

i have a list of listeners.
when an event happen i want to run throw the list and send all of them a message.
from some reason the next code doesn't work:

```
private List<Listener> internetListeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();
private Iterator<Listener> it;

public void updateInternetListeners(boolean state)
{       
    Listener listener;
    it = internetListeners.iterator();
    if (state)
        Log.d("Listener", "updating true");
    else
        Log.d("Listener", "updating false");
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        listener = (Listener)it.next();
        listener.onInternetStateChange(state);
    }
}
```

my activity which listens:

```
    @Override
public void onInternetStateChange(boolean state) {
    if (state)
        text.setText("Internet is On");
    else
        text.setText("Internet is Off");        
}
```

EDITED:
ok i found my problem...
this class extends BroadcastReceiver. and the list is inside this class. eveytime the internet state is change, it make a new instance of this class, and the listeners which are registered, are not available for this instance.. what shell i do ?

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by "doesn't work?"

Comment: i've edited and added my activity.. from some reason its now sending the state to the listener, although i know it got it write because when i register the listener, the registerListener function response with some text, which i see in the activity..

Comment: i think i maybe doing the whole going throw the list properly..

Answer (score 0):

You should not register listeners from a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`. As you noticed, this object is destroyed immediately upon `onReceive()` returning. A manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` cannot itself do anything that lasts beyond the end of `onReceive()`.

Comment: So a `Service` should be used, or data could be stored and recalled via `sqlite` in order to avoid an always-running `Service`.

Comment: i don't get it, in one hand android gives me system ability to be modified as soon as the internet state is changed, and on the other hand i cant make an event handler for that change ??

Comment: @AsafNevo: I do not know what you think "as soon as the internet state is changed" means. You also have declined to state why you think you need a list of app-specific listeners. You are welcome to listen to broadcasts like `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`. Usually, you would not do this from a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`, which appears to be what you are doing. Since you have not explained what it is you are trying to do, though, it is difficult to provide you with much concrete advice.

Comment: i've made an internet state change event handler.
the broadcast recevier get the action and send it to a class which have listeners (i've made a new class for it, after what u have written).
for example i have an activity as a listener an a thread as a listener.
on both i've implemented an onInternetStateChange method which react to the change in the sate..

Comment: @AsafNevo: "for example i have an activity as a listener" -- it is possible for you to have a `BroadcastReceiver` that works closely with an `Activity`. However, you need to get rid of the `<receiver>` element and register your `BroadcastReceiver` *from the `Activity`* via `registerReceiver()`. Typically, you would have the `BroadcastReceiver` be an inner class of the `Activity`, so the `BroadcastReceiver` can just call methods on the `Activity` as needed, bypassing the need for a listener interface.

Comment: @AsafNevo: "an a thread as a listener" -- you cannot have a thread floating around, disassociated from any Android component (e.g., activity).